# Can I use actual param names in jsp fmt:messages instead of index numbers? If so, how?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am looking to pass messages to jsp using fmt:message and fmt:params. Inside of the message file, I will have something like: `hello-world-name= Hello World, {0)`. Instead of the `{0}`, I would like this to actually be something like `{name}`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, but you can always define your own class extending `ListResourceBundle` (make sure it's available in your web application classpath) and provide here the message interpretation logic you want, then with the tag

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="yourPackage.yourClass">
```

you can use your custom resource bundle in your jsp ([here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jstl-fmt-message-tag) is an example... obviously you have to make your own custom class).